# Datagridview linked to datatable not getting updated

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

This is a part of simultaneous url download program that i'm trying to make. It has the url list saved in a datatable named `tbl` and it is bound to a datagridview named `dgvUrls`. Evrytime it encounters a dead url, it removes it from the datatable.

I've reproduced the error using the code below. The `Button3_Click` adds 100 rows to the datatable, makes it as the datasource for datagridview. The `q()` removes the rows one at a time by removing the 1st row. The prob is that the datagridview don't reflect the changes made in the datatable

```
    Dim tbl = New DataTable

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'Add 100 urls, for simplicity i'm adding only integers
    tbl.Columns.Add("Urls")
    For i = 1 To 100
        tbl.Rows.Add(i)
    Next

    'bind to datagridview so that the end user can see the urls being download/removed from the list 
    dgvUrls.DataSource = tbl

    'start multithread download , for simplicited (of this question) we have only one
    Dim t As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf Download)
    t.Start()

   t.Join()
   dgvUrls.Refresh()

End Sub

Private Sub download()
    'for simplicity, the 1st 80 urls were dead!
    For i = 1 To 80
        'we remove the dead urls
        tbl.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
    Next
```

Comment: You have updated your code with mine. Good thing. Now update the last bit: datagridview refresh after the other thread is over (try t.Join()  please) and we are done :)

Comment: @varocarbas, ok, i'm adding *t.Join()    dgvUrls.Refresh()*

Comment: @varocarbas now i get this error http://postimg.org/image/myjj7tj39/

Comment: This error is pretty descriptive and does nothing to do with multi-threading or with refreshing the data (or with this question): but with your multiple-deleting attitude (as I warned in my answer) :) Say OK to all the messages and you will see the DataGridView updated. To test this code properly, just delete 1 or 2 rows and confirm that everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is a good thing to `Refresh` the `DataGridView`, mainly if you are performing the modifications from another thread; something like this:

```
Dim t As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf q)
t.Start()
t.Join() 'Waits for the other thread to complete, such that the next line is reached on the right moment

dgvUrls.Refresh()
```

I deleted `Dim ts As ThreadStart = New ThreadStart(AddressOf q)` because is not necessary. Also you don't need the `Sleep` and `DoEvents`:

```
Private Sub q()
    For i = 1 To 98
        tbl.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
    Next
End Sub
```

As a proof of concept (to understand how all this works) is OK; but you should review various ideas in your logic before going further: removing so many rows from the `DataSource` can provoke problems (you would see that it triggers errors); ideally, (at least, I prefer it) you should modify the `DataGridView` directly (if possible) to avoid info-synchronisation problems; if you deal with multiple threads you would have to set up a "more proper structure" (the proposed `t.Join()` should be seen as a temporary fix to make this work).

Comment: Actually, it is a part of file download program. *Thread.Sleep(10)* is a mimic of file download. And if the file cant not be downloaded then the url is removed from the table. I cantnot use *t.Join()* as the download is multi-threaded and download Async

Comment: *modify the DataGridView directly* is not possible as i get cross-thread error :(

Comment: *"more proper structure"*.... hmm.. i dont knw what to do. But i used SyncLock :)

Comment: @NokImchen you are not in the GUI thread?! You should have said that. Also the Join is just something temporary (as explained). You should refresh the datagridview from a GUI thread after the deletion is completed.

Comment: @NokImchen you have to describe your situation properly. I just read your code and assumed that you were in the GUI thread. You have to be in the GUI thread to deal with GUI elements. Otherwise you would have to accept the behaviour without being able to do anything.

Comment: sorry, my explanation and way of asking is very poor... Well, i wanted to do everything using a seperate threat so that my main form dont get frozen. Anyways, *refresh the datagridview from a GUI* seems to be my only rescue :(

Comment: @NokImchen One sec... There was a misunderstanding here. You are in the GUI thread, the thread outside is "t". Don't worry then, you can use this code.

Comment: @NokImchen Let me describe what I think that you have here and you can correct any point where I am wrong...

Comment: i think i need to update the question or make a new question, cos the prob is getting complicated :(

Comment: @NokImchen the problem is understanding your situation. Let me try some quick questions, helping me (and any other person) to get a quick grasp of your situation: FIRST QUESTION: is the code above dgvUrls.DataSource = tbl in the main/gui thread?

Comment: @NokImchen I mean... is the method associated to an event of a GUI element (button). Why do you think that it is not in the main thread? If you create a new project, add a button and a datagridview to it and this code, it would work (you would get error messages because of deleting so many rows but the DataGridView would be updated and your problem solved).

Comment: yes, *dgvUrls.DataSource = tbl* is in the main thread. But *tbl.Rows.RemoveAt(x)* is in a seperate thread

Comment: @NokImchen I know that. That's why I didn't suggest you to update the datagridview from this thread but ONCE IT IS OVER (this is what t.join is for... after this line you are back in the main thread). Please try the code and confirm that your problem is solved.

Comment: i cant wait till it get over, cos there are lost of urls and waiting for all the urls to be downloaded and then ONLY refreshing the gui is not a good idea..

Comment: @NokImchen if you are in hurry, take it with calm :) If you want to test this code properly, delete a lower number of rows (to avoid these error messages). You can delete rows from the DataGridView directly, also would avoid these problems. Or you might take a while to think the number of rows you have, the ones you have deleted, and how many are remaining in the DGV. But, better focus on one problem at a time.